# Remove a category from breadcrumbs

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Is it possibly to remove a category (with no products assigned to it) from the breadcrumbs? It is only necessary as a top level item in the main menu but does not need a page. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What should happen once you click on this menu?

Comment: Question is not clear, Please explain with example thanks

Comment: I do not want the category to be included in the breadcrumbs.

Comment: only one category?

Comment: yes, just one category

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot, I don't understand the question. Why should it be in the breadcrumb when nothing is in it? Or does it have child categories? Why not move them out of the category?

Comment: For instance I want the EYEWEAR link to be in the main menu but not in breadcrumbs. The top level menu item does not have an href (there is no content in the EYEWEAR category) and it does not need a breadcrumb.    http://www.screencast.com/t/nrcEoNnI